# Can my "up" vote on Review Audits be treated as actual vote?

Tags: feature-request, review, voting, review-audits

While reviewing the First Posts queue and Late Answers queue I often come across [some](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/250610) [excellent](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/246218) [posts](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/246272) (both questions and answers) and up-vote them which later turn out to just be Review audits. However, my up-vote doesn't get registered as an actual up-vote and I have to go to my Review history to find the last item and once again cast my up-vote to actually vote upon the post.

Can my "up" vote on Review Audits be treated as actual vote?

This isn't of much concern in case of audits where posts should be deleted as our "up" (review failed!) / "down" votes doesn't matter there. Moreover, this is only for First Posts and Late Answers Review queues since we cannot vote on other Review interfaces.